# How to avoid missing status for Workflow access module permission just after node creation?

Tags: users, debugging, workflows

I am using [Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow) 7.x-2.8 to manage peer-reviewing publication.

When an authenticated user (an author) creates a post, he can choose a first workflow state transition from creation (by default) to draft. This draft is visible only for author and admin. This draft can be edited only by the author.

The sub-module Workflow Access allows me to manage permissions for each workflow state, which is really great. But, apparently, I have a problem with the first status assignment with Workflow Access (priority = 1).

Indeed, according to [Devel Node Access module (DNA)](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) debug mode, the status is not in node_access table and I need to rebuild permissions to clear the issue (which is OK for dev website but of course, it is not OK for production website).

When the permissions are rebuilt, everything is fine and the node_access table seems to be OK. Further, when the author decides to change the post to another workflow state (draft TO submitted), the permissions are correctly modified and the author can not edit the post anymore (pending approval).

Last detail : the content type related to this workflow is not published, by default.

I add a DNA screenshot and I hope everything is clear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem for me, but for a custom hook_node_access_records().

For me the solution to implement the hook_node_grants(). and clear the cache.

Once you use the hook_node_access_records, you have to implement the hook_node_grants.